# What is the name of this multiset-like object?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, multisets

My understanding is that a *multiset* (roughly, a set where we care about multiplicity) can be modeled as a function $V\to\Bbb{Card}$ with set-sized support, where $V$ is the class of all sets, $\Bbb{Card}$ is the class of all cardinalities, and set-sized support means the class of sets on which the function is nonzero is a set. (These in turn can be modeled within ZFC as sets of input-output pairs where you simply ignore all the inputs whose outputs are zero.)

A similar and natural object would be a function $V\to\Bbb Z$ with set-sized support. (Again, $V$ is the class of all sets.) This would be like a multiset except that we can no longer have infinitely many copies of an element, but we may have negatively many copies of it.

These form a group and an algebra, which makes them particularly natural to work with. Adjoining the constant function $1$ to our algebra makes things especially nice (though it raises some issues in representing these within ZFC), since it allows us to say things like, "if the multiplicities of the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are all $1$ (i.e. they're pure sets), then $X\cap Y=XY$ and $X\cup Y=1-(1-X)(1-Y)$". The principle of inclusion-exclusion is essentially the equation\begin{align}X\cup Y\cup Z&=1-(1-X)(1-Y)(1-Z)\\&=X+Y+Z-XY-XZ-YZ+XYZ.\end{align}

In any case, my question is: **do these natural objects (functions $V\to\Bbb Z$ with set-sized support, interpreted as variations on the multiset concept) have a name?** If so, what is it?

To be clear, the sort of answer I'm expecting is a *piece of terminology*. I want a word that can fill the blank in the following piece of dialogue: "The right way to think about this puzzle is to frame it in terms of _____s instead of just sets."

(If there *is* no name, as I'm starting to worry is the case, I'd appreciate your help in inventing one - though I'd appreciate if you didn't just open a dictionary and choose a word at random.)

Comment: it's called initial object in category theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects

Comment: @tp1 I'm sorry, I was under the impression that the initial object of the category of sets was the empty set, not these multiset-y things…

Comment: normally, you can create instances of category theory objects, if you have 1->A morphism available. But initial object concept replaces the 1 with I, and that allows then multisets. Then it'll be more like 1->I->A, where there will be multiple copies of the I object, and then  I->A will give multi-sets of the A object.

Comment: @tp1 If by $1$ you mean a singleton set, then that's the _terminal_ object in the category of sets. Replacing $1$ by other sets gives us [generalized elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element), but this concept is different both from multisets and from the thing I want to name.

Comment: yes, normally it's called generalized elements. multi-set concept can be found from the same category theory diagram, in the A object above, not in I or 1.

Comment: Idea: we could call them _signed multisets_